# Why am I getting negative sign for my java slope method?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java project. I have problem in Slope method! I am using a tester given by our instructor to run and test my code. When I run the program, the result says the expected output is 1.5, but I get -1.5. I can't figure out where I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

```java
//Segment.java
public class Segment implements SegmentInterface {
    // two Points that hold endpoints of the segment
    private Point p1;
    private Point p2;

    // Default constructor that will set the endpoints to new
    // Points with values (0,0) and (4,4)
    public Segment() {
        //this(0, 0, 4, 4);
        this.p1 = new Point(0, 0);
        this.p2 = new Point(4, 4);
    }

    // Parameterized constructor that accepts (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    // and creates and sets the endpoints
    public Segment(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {

        //this.p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
        //this.p2 = new Point(x2, y2);

        if(x1 == x2 && y1 == y2){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Points can't have a lenght of 0!");
        } 

        else{
            this.p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
            this.p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
    }
}

     //A parameterized constructor that accepts (Point p1, Point p2) and sets both
     //the endpoints to a deep copy of the Points that are passed in.
     //Make sure to check to see if both Points are equal.  This would be a
     //theoretical "Segment" of length 0 which is not allowed, so throw a new
     //IllegalArgumentException.
    public Segment(Point p1, Point p2) {

        this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
        this.p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());

            if(p1.equals(p2)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Points cannot have same values!");
            } 
}

    // Copy constructor that accepts a Segment and initializes the data (of the
    // new Segment being created) to be the same as the Segment that was
    // received.
    public Segment(Segment other) {

        this(other.p1, other.p2);

        //if(other.p1 == other.p2){
            //throw new IllegalArgumentException("Undefine!");
        //}

}

/*
         * The slope method returns the slope of the Segment as a double.   If the segment
         * is vertical, the slope is undefined.  In that case, Java will return
         * Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY or Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, depending on which way you
         * subtract to calculate the slope.   You can either check for division by zero or
         * let Java do the calculation.  However, your requirements are to ALWAYS return
         * Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY if the slope is undefined.
         *
         * Also, strangely enough, Java may return 0 or -0 for a slope which is horizontal.
         * Your requirements are to always return a slope of 0 for a horizontal line
         * (don’t always just return the Java calculation).
         */
    public double slope() {

        if(p1.getY() == p2.getY()){
            return 0;
        }
            else if(p1.getX() == p2.getX()){
                double inf = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            return inf;
            }

            else{

            return ((double) (p2.getY() - p1.getY())
                    / (p1.getX() - p2.getX()));
        }

    }
```

This a part of my code!

Comment: Please try to the minimum code that is required for the problem. All the comments/commented out code/teacher's instructions are not essential and distract from the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Right here:

```
return ((double) (p2.getY() - p1.getY())
                / (p1.getX() - p2.getX()));
```

Should be

```
return ((double) (p2.getY() - p1.getY())
                / (p2.getX())-p1.getX() );
```

Since the slope formula says that m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

Comment: I do not see any difference! Though I copy and pasted in my code but did not work! Still same output...!

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying! I have no idea why here it shows in a different order, but in my code it is y2 - y1 / x2 - x1. Thank you though!

Comment: Is it working now? Because if that was the only mistake, this code is functionally sound.
Also, you can simply `return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;` No need to create a value to hold it :)

Comment: Now I only get error on 0 and infinity. I am supposed to get zero and infinity, but I get negative zero and negative infinity!! Any idea what my mistake could be?

Comment: How are you getting negative 0? Do you mean when you use 0,0 and 0,0 as inputs you get negative 0, and when you use inf,inf and inf,inf as inputs you get negative infinity?

Comment: I am using a program given me by my instructor. So I run that program to test my code. It shows me where I am doing wrong. my code compiles fine but after running the tester, it says Expected output: 0 your output: -0. and same for infinity

Comment: Hmm odd. Have stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: No, do not know how to do it! :)

Comment: if you're using eclipse, check out [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) tutorial